# Knockout: select element options binding + value binding + optionsCaption binding + late ajax response = weird

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-2.0

Consider the following ko bindings on a `select` element:

```
<select data-bind="value: valueObservable, options: optionsObservableArray, 
    optionsCaption: '[None] - this is an optional field'">
```

... given a viewmodel like the following:

```
function MyViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.valueObservable = ko.observable();
    self.optionsObservableArray = ko.observableArray();

    // ajax call to load options
    ko.computed(function() {
        $.ajax(...)
        .success(function(optionsResponse) {
            self.optionsObservableArray(optionsResponse)
        });
    });

    // ajax call to load data value
    ko.computed(function() {
        $.ajax(...)
        .success(function(valueResponse) {
            self.valueObservable(valueResponse)
        });
    });
}
```

What's weird about this is when the second (data) ajax call returns before the first (options) ajax call. Since the `select` element has an `optionsCaption` binding, here is what I believe is happening:

1. The data ajax call completes, setting the `valueObservable` to some value (like 6, abc, or some other non-falsy value).
2. Because there is only 1 `option` in the `select` element (due to the `optionsCaption`), and because the `valueObservable` is bound to it (via the `value` binding), this causes the `valueObservable` to be changed to `undefined`.
3. Finally, the `optionsObservableArray` completes and adds new `option` elements to the `select`, but by this time it is too late: The `valueObservable` is now wrapping an `undefined` value rather than the real data value returned from the first ajax call.

Question: What is the best way to work around this? Here is what I can think of:

1. Make the first ajax call run with `async: false`. This may slow page rendering.
2. Create a separate observable for binding to the select value (such as `value: selectedValueObservable`). Then subscribe to the `optionsObservableArray` and use the subscription to do something like `self.selectedValueObservable(self.valueObservable())`. This seems like a bandaid fix.
3. Render the select & options to the page before any javascript executes by sending the options data from the server (using MVC viewmodel). This makes it a little more difficult to deal with the options as an `observableArray`.

**Update**

There is another concern which I omitted from this question to simplify the example code. In actuality, this viewmodel is used to create an editable list of data items. So there is actually more than 1 dropdown list that gets rendered to the page. The data ajax call really returns an array, and its success function really sets an `observableArray` of complex items. Since the dropdown list options are reused in every inline form, it is placed on the `$parent` viewmodel and only loaded once. It is also difficult to pass the select options in a single ajax call because the data items are retrieved via WebAPI (which returns an `IEnumerable`, no room to send additional dropdown options).

Comment: What is the reason to wrap ajax call into `computed` ?

Comment: @vittore, wrapping the ajax call in a `ko.computed` causes it to be executed immediately. Basically it initializes the viewmodel by sending the ajax calls off when the viewmodel is constructed.

Comment: there are many other way to execute function immediately, and `computed` doesnt seem to be designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have one ajax call if it is possible. Make your controller to return complex object with array of objects and selected value:

```
// ajax call to load options and data value
ko.computed(function() {
    $.ajax(...)
    .success(function(response) {
        self.optionsObservableArray(response.options);
        self.valueObservable(response.value);
    });
});
```

If it is impossible to merge two ajax call you can put calling of the second ajax to success callback of the first ajax:

```
// ajax call to load options
ko.computed(function() {
    $.ajax(...)
    .success(function(optionsResponse) {
        self.optionsObservableArray(optionsResponse)

        // ajax call to load data value
        $.ajax(...)
        .success(function(valueResponse) {
             self.valueObservable(valueResponse)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your first suggestion is not feasible in my case since all of the ajax calls hit WebAPI, not MVC (I have updated the question to reflect this). The second option would work, though I'm not sure I like the idea of serial chaining as a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason not to make ajax call first and applyBinding on done ?

```
$.when(getOptions(), getData()).done(bind) 


function getOptions() { 
    return $.ajax(...).success(vm.optionsObservableArray)
}

function getData() {
    return $.ajax(...).success(vm.valueObservable)
}

function bind() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('elem')) 
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. It's a little more complex than this though, because the vm takes a dependency on the getData() function. Editing a single item in the array can change the sort order in which the items should appear, so after editing, I would want to rebind the whole array (and I use the ko.mapping plugin to do this) to enforce the new sort order. This is why I have the vm encapsulating the function to make the ajax call, rather than having it outside of the vm construction and binding code.

Comment: you can execute that within your viewmodel, noone prevent you from doing that. `bind` is just an example , as both success handlers which i put as example only.

Comment: my point is to execute binding to DOM after you got all the data, as you cant render DOM properly prior to that moment anyway.

Comment: I agree, there is nothing stopping me from using these functions within the viewmodel. However, what are the major differences between doing it this way, and having immediately executed viewmodel-encapsulated `$.ajax` functions that execute with `async: false`? In both cases, `applyBindings` does not happen until after all data is received, right? In reality, the editable form is hidden from the user initially, but read data is shown. The user can click to edit the item and display the form, so delaying the load of the select options is acceptable from a requirements perspective.

Comment: In your code applyBindings is executed _before_ data is received.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, because I currently don't have `async: false` in the ajax calls. If I was to put `async: false` in the ajax calls, `applyBindings` would be executed *after* data is received. I mentioned that as a possible fix. I'm not discounting your solution, I am just wondering if it is better than the option of having a separate observable bound to the value of the select element in my scenario. That is my current workaround, and it accomplishes what I need without making the vm wait for the options before it can display read-only data on the page.

Comment: After reading all your updates I feel like i do need to see whole picture of what are you doing, can you put an example on jsfiddle or something? (it support ajax/echo so you can have you ajax calls in there)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18114/discussion-between-vittore-and-danludwig)